# Center Table==> width:100%; margin: 0 auto;) not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Yes there's a billion posts on this topic and this is ironic because I've centered many tables before..
 But the "answer" is not working.  I am using a Database.net plug in table (which could be why?) Link to Codepen: https://codepen.io/ScottFSchmidt/pen/eemrBG

Also, I want to be able to maintain like a 80%+ width. On "solution" worked but then the table was small because it had 50% width.

```
table {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.table {
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    float: none;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This is bootstrap 3 FYI not 4 so it’s not a duplicate

Comment: update you code and add  you html code too

Comment: Can you please try, in css. table { padding: 0 20%;} I have modified your codepen.

Comment: It might be because I didn’t clear my cache because it looks centered on my phone but hard to tell. Is it center for anyone else? I’m at lunch

Comment: This table is bootstrap 3 not 4 from what I remember...

Comment: You are using [Bootstrap 4's style sheet](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css). In any case, the solution of moving `.table-responsive` to the container [seems to work for me](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POwdJw).

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Table is easily centered.

Comment: Ok. Thanks I’ll move it to the doc. In the link it says bootstrap 3.5 or something. I got it from the cdn website. Why they put 3.5 if it’s 4? Confusing

Comment: Table is centered now. 20% padding as someone suggested seemed to work

Comment: From what I see in your CodePen, you're using Bootstrap 3.3.5 JavaScript and Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.2 CSS.

Comment: Yeah you’re right I didn’t check my links I imported code from a previous project. I deleted bootstrap 4 good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
  padding-left:20%;
  padding-right:20%;
```

Also, Bootstrap 4 does not allow 100% width.

Thanks to all who commented!